# SQL filtering with select VS lambda filtering with memory

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite, lambda

I have a program in C# for a Church service where you can select a song from a list and put on a projector or a screen. This list is currently saved in .txt files (I made it several years ago) and currently I have about 270 different songs.

In the program you can filter and search by the title of the song and by the content of the song. This is very expensive as every time I search some text, the program checks each of the 270 songs in txt files: it opens, reads and closes, each of them every time.

Now I want to change and create a DB (SQLite) to save and search the songs and the verses from there.

My doubt is the following, if I make a select every time I want to consult, filter or search a song, **what is better in a performance view**? Is better to load everything in memory and create Lambda functions to improve searches and filters? Or is better to make every operation through SQL?

Thanks!

PD: I add some numbers:

270 songs: in disk space is about 1 MB in total.

5-6 strophes per song: 1.620 strophes.

4-5 verses per strophe: 8.100 verses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news is that you do not have to care. See, any database written like in the last 60 years or so will keep whatever it can in memory anyway as long as there is enough memory. So, unless you unload SqlLite and if you set sensible memory limits, the database ends up in memory anyway. Your (implied) assumption that the query hits storage would be a colossal failure to properly use the database. Particularly given how pathetic (1mb in total) it is - we do not talk of a dozen gigabyte memory db that may challenge memory, the db is small enough to end up in the CPU cache.